# How do I use calculus of variations to prove that Carnot cycle is the most efficient one?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, variational-calculus, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

There are already many questions on Physics SE asking for a proof of the maximum possible efficiency of Carnot's engine. However, none of them (at least the ones which I looked up) contain a mathematically rigorous proof involving variational calculus.

When I felt like proving it, the natural thought was to use variational calculus, but I am just not sure how to do this. Also, is it even possible to prove it using calculus of variations? If yes, then how?

Comment: Maybe the following can help: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7a18/1a73d79cfba6f11433c9cb219a81a644445c.pdf

Comment: At first blush it seems to me that *"the natural thought was to use variational calculus"* is reasonble *given a particular system* (say the monatomic ideal gas, perhaps) because you need a well defined function over which to minimize. But the usual proofs are more powerful than that: they don't rely on defining a particular system.

Comment: @dmckee Some of the *usual* proofs which I have seen require the knowledge of a few concepts of physics which are out of my scope. So I thought why not derive it way which I am familiar with, even though it might be long. You can just drop a hint if it's too long. That's perfectly fine.(*BTW I am a high-schooler, which is the main reason why I am not so familiar with those "few concepts".*)

Comment: @dmckee Another reason for this question is because I think (at least in this case) I need to know a rigorous way tomprove such kind of results, somin the future, when I encounter similar questions, I can approach them with a general technique.

Comment: @dmckee *"...because you need a well defined function over which to minimize."* That is precisely the reason why I am stuck.

Comment: My point is that (unless someone else is rather more clever than I'm being) your approach will allow you to prove that the Carnot cycle is optimal of the ideal gas (hopefully for all values of $\gamma$ in one go), then separately for the van der Waals gas, then for model X, then model Y , then... But an exhaustive search is impractical and the more general you try to make the models the more intricate each calculation becomes.

Comment: @dmckee Oh! I get your point. I was misunderstanding the older comment. I completely agree with you. And now I am seeing the reasons for this approach not being a good one. But I'll wait for a few days, hoping that a new elegant proof gets discovered by the means of this question ;)

Comment: If you know the calculus of variations then you have all the mathematical tools you need for classical thermodynamics. If you also know about thermal expansion, heat capacities, and latent heats at the level of high school physics class then you have all the foundational physical knowledge that you need to begin. The classical treatment develops eveything you need from there (because that is where the founders of the discipline were when they started). It's not easy (and rigor is usually skipped at first and added the second (or third) time round), but it is within your grasp.

Comment: see such an attempt in https://www.ijee.ie/articles/Vol14-6/ijee1031.pdf

Comment: Well, @hyportnex, Prof. Wang makes me feel silly. I've been [a big proponent of using the T-S plane](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/459864/520) where appropriate. Of course that approach leave the task of finding the isotherma and isentropic paths for each system still to be done, but it shows that those are the right paths to find.

Comment: @dmckee don't feel that way (in the spirit of the Holiday season) , I for one do not think that this is a particularly successful attempt.

Comment: @dmckee for T-S plane analysis see this and also Tobin's original paper in AJP,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/300347/optimality-of-the-carnot-cycle. The Wang paper reference is from Pirx. I prefer Tobin's way over Wang's especially because Wang seemingly hides the problems "under the rug" of his function $\psi(dS)$ (Eq. 19).